# Cómo realizar operaciones de agregación en campos JSONb

Tags: python, json, django, agregación

Tengo un modelo donde se almacenan transacciones (deposito/compra) de una tarjeta de combustible para vehículos.

Son dos modelos, el de Autos y el de Gasolina.

```
class Auto(Model):
    placas = models.CharField(max_length=10, help_text="Escribe las placas del auto")

class Gasolina(Model):
    auto = models.ForeignKey(Auto, related_name='gas_transacciones')
    fecha = models.DateField()
    cantidad = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    deposito = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    data = JSONField()
```

Estos son mis datos de prueba:

```
[
  {
    "auto": 1, "cantidad": "300.00",
    "data": {
      "precio": 17.87
    },
    "deposito": false, "fecha": "2017-06-17", "id": 1
  },
  {
    "auto": 1, "cantidad": "250.00",
    "data": {
      "precio": 17.46
    },
    "deposito": false, "fecha": "2017-06-17", "id": 2
  },
  {
    "auto": 1, "cantidad": "280.00",
    "data": {
      "precio": 17.51
    },
    "deposito": false, "fecha": "2017-06-17", "id": 3
  }
]
```

Lo que intento hacer es obtener el promedio de los valores de un determinado `auto` que se encuentran en el campo `precio` cuando `deposito` es `false`.

Hago lo siguiente:

```
>>> from django.db.models import Avg
>>> from apps.gas.models import Auto, Gasolina
>>> a = Auto.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> a.gas_transacciones.all()
<QuerySet [<Gasolina: 2017-06-17 - 300.00>, <Gasolina: 2017-06-17 - 250.00>, <Gasolina: 2017-06-17 - 280.00>]>
```

Ahora bien, para obtener el promedio, use lo siguiente:

```
>>> a.gas_transacciones.filter(deposito=False).aggregate(Avg('data__precio'))
```

Pero tengo el siguiente error:

> ```
> FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'precio' into field. 
> Join on 'data' not permitted.
> ```

Tampoco puedo extraer solo los valores de `precio`, por el mismo error.

```
>>> a.gas_transacciones.all().values('data__precio')
```

#### Pregunta

¿Cómo puedo obtener ya el promedio de precios o solo los valores de `precio` de un campo tipo JSONb?

> #### Nota
>
> Uso Django 1.11.2. La base de de datos es PostgreSQL 9.5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me ha costado pero ya lo tengo, primero lo intenté con `KeyTransform` para obtener solo los precios y funciona ok.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import KeyTransform
Gasolina.objects.all().annotate(
precio=KeyTransform('precio', 'data')).values('precio')
```

Pero por alguna razón eso no funciona para hacer el AVG. No se puede usar `KeyTranform`

```
Gasolina.objects.all().annotate(
    precio=KeyTransform('precio', 'data')).aggregate(models.Avg('precio'))

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: function avg(jsonb) does not exist
```

Asumo que postgres no soporta ni el `avg` ni el `sum` sobre el jsonb(pero si el `count`), lo cual es raro, si alguien lo puede explicar, lo agradecería.

Por lo cual, nos queda usar "la vieja confiable" y el`RawSQL` para obtener el precio en una nueva columna y luego promediar esa columna:

```
Gasolina.objects.all().annotate(precio=models.expressions.RawSQL("(data->>%s)::numeric",('precio',))).aggregate(models.Avg('precio'))
```

Comment: Funcionó perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

Enfrente el mismo problema y solo quería ampliar la respuesta aceptada con el uso ORM de Django sin RawSQL, porque el autor preguntaba si alguien lo explica.
Después de 5 años se cambiaron algunas de las cosas en Django, así que incluiré los imports actualizados (uso Django 4.0).

```
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db.models import FloatField, Avg
from django.db.models.fields.json import KeyTransform

Gasolina.objects.all().annotate(precio=Cast(KeyTransform('precio', 'data'), FloatField())).aggregate(Avg('precio'))
```

Como lo vemos, `RawSQL("(data->>%s)::numeric",('precio',))` se convierte en `Cast(KeyTransform('precio', 'data'), FloatField())`.
Es decir solo faltaba forzar conversion a un tipo especifico como FloatField.